# What does it mean by "wound" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Smoke from the engine drifted over the heads of the chattering crowd, while cats of every color **wound** here and there between their legs.

It's from Harry potter and I definetely looked up the definition of 'wind' as a verb in the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wind) and a lot more, but I couldn't find one that fits in that sentence.

I can picture that scene through the context but I wanna know the exact definition of the word. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What English language dictionaries did you consult? Can you visualize the paths of the cats as they travel among the legs of the people in the crowd? What course does a river follow among the hills? Do any of the example sentences in the dictionaries you consulted mention **rivers**? Look closely! (The answer is right there in the Cambridge dictionary entry you link to here!)

Comment: It's pretty much the dictionary meaning of wound that you seek.

Comment: @ P. E. Dant So "If a road,path, or river winds, it follows a route that turns repeatedly in different directions" is what it means here? The definition says "If a road/path/river", so I thought it's not the right one either since the subject in my sentence is "cat"..

Comment: Visualize the path of the cat. Is it straight, or does it go this way and that? Are there any novels written in your native language? Is there poetry written in your native language? Do writers use _imagery_ in your native language? They do the same thing in English!

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks so much I got it now. It's quite hard to read novels as a non native English speaker cause I'm used to 'studying' english.. thanks!

Comment: Congratulations! You have _exactly_ the right idea: stop "studying", use your imagination, and you'll be fine.